# Show new opened apps icons in Plank to the left?

Tags: release-freya, plank

I have my most used apps pinned to the rightmost part of Plank.

This is the more natural position for me, since I am right-handed and that's where my hand goes when I lower my mouse.

When I open new apps, they open also *to the right* of Plank, which actually *moves* the default position of my pinned apps.

I'd like to know if there's a way to force new apps to show in Plank *to the leftmost* part of the bar, or at least to the left of some selected group of pinned tabs.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see it's not possible.
The only way I found to preserve the position of the dock items, is to set the plank alignment to left-aligned or in panel mode with items aligned to the left.

But because you want to have your apps aligned to the right, this is probably NOT the way you want it.

If you still want to try it, here is how:
*Option 1*:

1. Press Ctrl and perform a right click on the plank
2. Open Settings
3. Set alignment to left-aligned OR select panel-mode *Not sure if it's called like that, because I'm using a different language*
4. If you selected panel-mode you'll have to set the alignment of the items to left-aligned.
5. Now the plank should be aligned to the left and new apps don't move the apps which are already in the plank.

*Option 2:*

1. Open `~/.config/plank/dock1/settings` with a text editor
2. Change `Alignment=3` to `Alignment=1` *(for left-aligned)* OR change  `Alignment=3` to `Alignment=0` *(for panel mode)*

   1. If you choose panel mode, set `ItemsAlignment=3` to `ItemsAlignment=1`
3. Now the plank should be aligned to the left and new apps don't move the apps which are already in the plank.